# Wondering how to share column definitions between two grids?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am wondering how to share column definitions between two grids, by placing the column definitions into a style?

The reason? I want to share these column definitions between two separate grids. The grids have about 20 columns, so it's a lot of work to copy'n'paste things across all of the grids to keep them synched up.

Here is a sample grid:

```
<dxg:GridControl ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsSource}">
    <dxg:GridControl.Columns>
        <dxg:GridColumn x:Name="Codice" Binding="{Binding Codice}" FieldName="Codice"/>
        <dxg:GridColumn x:Name="Nome" Binding="{Binding Nome}" FieldName="Nome"/>
    </dxg:GridControl.Columns>
</dxg:GridControl>
```

## What I have tried

I have already attempted to shift the column definitions into a style, so I could share the column definitions between the two grids, however, I kept getting the error `Property 'Visual Tree' does not support values of type 'GridColumn'`.

Comment: Why you don't create a UserControl with this Grid and use the UserControl everywhere you wan't to access the grid?

Comment: @take Unfortunately, this won't work, as one grid is a master/detail grid, and the other grid is a master grid. The column definitions between the `<dxg:GridControl.Columns>` tags are shared between them, but the  rest of the grid is quite different.

Answer (score 3):

Based on the code you posted, it looks (even though you don't mention it), you are using DevExpress' GridControl.

If so, you have `ColumnSource` property, where you can bind to a list of objects representing a column (not necessarily `GridColumn` objects).

This link explains it better than I would: https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/CustomDocument10121 but to summarize:

1. You create a list of objects (of a type you can create, but you can use `GridColumn` if you wish. If you are using MVVM this should be on your ViewModel so using `GridColumn` is not wise) which stores the data needed to create a `GridColumn` and assign it to the `ColumnsSource` property on your `GridControl`
2. You make a `DataTemplate` (or several if you require different column types), which templates a `GridColumn` based on the data in your object (if your object is already a `GridColumn` it's a matter of defining it again, but this is mandatory)
3. You create a `DataTemplateSelector` descendant which chooses (by overriding the `SelectTemplate` function) which template to apply (if you only have one, you can just return that one without any other logic) and assign it to the `ColumnGeneratorTemplateSelector` property on the `GridControl`

It's all explained in the link above, and would make for a too long answer here, but hope that can get you started

DevExpress has samples of this on the `MVVM` sections of their demos, and the documentation is fairly good.

Except for the template selector, it can all be done in XAML

So once you have this, is just a matter of assigning the same "column definition object" list to each `GridControl`'s `ColumnsSource` property, and you can share it to as many grid controls as you want.

## Update

It's been a long time since I did this, but watching old sources of mine, it might be possible that if you just feed a `GridColumn` collection to the `ColumnSource` property you might not need to use a template selector at all. I recall this not being possible (although by that time I tested a lot of component suites and it wasn't possible in some), but I see it done in my own code and don't see anywhere obvious where I choose a `ColumnTemplateSelector`

Answer (score 0):

I think use `AutoGenerateColumns="True"` on the `DataGrid` would be your best option